# How to fix - Excel VBA copy and paste values - ThisWorkbook error

Tags: excel, vba

**I'm setting up a copy/paste macro for my financial model.**

While it is currently running just fine, I am having trouble making if I save a new version of the model. The model has basic tabs I need to paste over as well as several tabs that operate on toggles and cycle through 10-15 sheets, so I have pasted an example of one sheet and one cycle in the code.

*Copy_PasteWorkbook.xlsm* is a blank excel document utilized as the location of the pasting.

Right now it will only work if I define the name of the file its running in and I cannot get *Workbook(ThisWorkbook)* to work in the code.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Application.Calculate

Windows("Copy_PasteWorkbook.xlsx").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Model"
Windows("XYZ_v1.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Value_Summary_Sheet").Select
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Copy_PasteWorkbook.xlsx").Activate
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=8
Sheets("Model").Select
Sheets("Model").Name = Cells(1, 3).Value
Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Windows("XYZ_v1.xlsm").Activate
Range("A1").Select

Sheets("Inputs").Range("Selected_Toggle_Number").Value = 1

Do Until Sheets("Inputs").Range("Selected_Toggle_Number").Value > Sheets("Inputs").Range("Total_Toggles").Value

Application.Calculate

Windows("Copy_PasteWorkbook.xlsx").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
ActiveSheet.Name = "Model"
Windows("XYZ_v1.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Financial Models").Select
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Select
Selection.Copy
Windows("Copy_PasteWorkbook.xlsx").Activate
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=8
Sheets("Model").Select
Sheets("Model").Name = Cells(1, 3).Value
Range("A1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Windows("XYZ_v1.xlsm").Activate
Range("A1").Select

Sheets("Inputs").Range("Selected_Toggle_Number").Value = Sheets("Inputs").Range("Selected_Toggle_Number").Value + 1

DoEvents
Loop

Sheets("Inputs").Range("Selected_Toggle_Number").Value = 1

Sheets("Inputs").Select
Range("A1").Select

Application.CommandBars("Clipboard").Visible = True
On Error Resume Next 'incase clipboard IS empty
Application.CommandBars("Clipboard").FindControl(ID:=3634).Execute
Application.CommandBars("Clipboard").Visible = False

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

Ideally I would like to sub out the Windows("XYZ_V1.xlsm").Activate code with ThisWorkbook so that it can function whenever changes are made to the model. Right now if I update and save a new version I then have to update the code throughout for the new name.

Comment: `Workbook(ThisWorkbook)` use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` Please format all code in your questions

Comment: Hi - thank you for the assistance. I am new to writing in VBA, so apologies on the formatting. I tried to implement your edits for the top part of the code and am having an issue running it. I replaced Windows("XYZ_v1.xlsm").Activate
Sheets("Value_Summary_Sheet").Select with the above suggestions. How should I be interpreting your edits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer took me a while, but since you are new I thought it was better to show you how and where your code was changed.

Once you delete all the comments the code is way shorter:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wbPaste As Workbook, wsSumary As Worksheet, wsPaste As Worksheet, wsInputs As Worksheet, _
    wsFinMod As Worksheet

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'First you need to avoid using select, in that matter you need worksheet and workbook variables
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'the workbook containing the code
    Set wbPaste = Workbooks("Copy_PasteWorkbook.xlsx") 'the workbook where you are going to paste
    With wb
        Set wsSumary = .Sheets("Value_Summary_Sheet")
        Set wsInputs = .Sheets("Inputs")
        Set wsFinMod = .Sheets("Financial Models")
    End With

    'The code above sets your worksheets and workbooks on the macro file

    With wbPaste
        Set wsPaste = .Sheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    End With

    'the code above sets the paste workbook, adds a sheet and names it "Model", also equals to this:

'        Windows("Copy_PasteWorkbook.xlsx").Activate
'        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
'        ActiveSheet.Name = "Model"

    With wsPaste
        wsSumary.UsedRange.Copy
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues '?¿?¿ I assume from your code you want to paste it there
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .Name = .Cells(1, 3)
    End With

    'The code above equals to this:

'        Windows("XYZ_v1.xlsm").Activate
'        Sheets("Value_Summary_Sheet").Select
'        Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Select
'        Selection.Copy
'        Windows("Copy_PasteWorkbook.xlsx").Activate
'        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
'            :=False, Transpose:=False
'        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
'            SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=8
'        Sheets("Model").Select
'        Sheets("Model").Name = Cells(1, 3).Value
'        Range("A1").Select
'        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Dim i As Long, x As Long, wsTemp As Worksheet
    x = wsInputs.Range("Total_Toggles").Value
    For i = 1 To x
        Application.Calculate
        With wbPaste
            Set wsTemp = .Sheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        End With
        With wsTemp
            wsFinMod.UsedRange.Copy
            .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .Name = .Cells(1, 3)
        End With
    Next i

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .CutCopyMode = False
    End With

    'The code above equals to this:

'        Windows("XYZ_v1.xlsm").Activate
'        Range("A1").Select
'        Sheets("Inputs").Range("Selected_Toggle_Number").Value = 1
'        Do Until Sheets("Inputs").Range("Selected_Toggle_Number").Value > Sheets("Inputs").Range("Total_Toggles").Value
'            Application.Calculate
'            Windows("Copy_PasteWorkbook.xlsx").Activate
'            ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
'            ActiveSheet.Name = "Model"
'            Windows("XYZ_v1.xlsm").Activate
'            Sheets("Financial Models").Select
'            Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Select
'            Selection.Copy
'            Windows("Copy_PasteWorkbook.xlsx").Activate
'            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
'                :=False, Transpose:=False
'            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
'                SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=8
'            Sheets("Model").Select
'            Sheets("Model").Name = Cells(1, 3).Value
'            Range("A1").Select
'            Application.CutCopyMode = False
'            Windows("XYZ_v1.xlsm").Activate
'            Range("A1").Select
'            Sheets("Inputs").Range("Selected_Toggle_Number").Value = Sheets("Inputs").Range("Selected_Toggle_Number").Value + 1
'            DoEvents
'        Loop
'
'        Sheets("Inputs").Range("Selected_Toggle_Number").Value = 1
'        Sheets("Inputs").Select
'        Range("A1").Select
'        Application.CommandBars("Clipboard").Visible = True
'        On Error Resume Next 'incase clipboard IS empty
'        Application.CommandBars("Clipboard").FindControl(ID:=3634).Execute
'        Application.CommandBars("Clipboard").Visible = False
'        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This is how your code would look like:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wbPaste As Workbook, wsSumary As Worksheet, wsPaste As Worksheet, wsInputs As Worksheet, _
    wsFinMod As Worksheet

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'First you need to avoid using select, in that matter you need worksheet and workbook variables
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'the workbook containing the code
    Set wbPaste = Workbooks("Copy_PasteWorkbook.xlsx") 'the workbook where you are going to paste
    With wb
        Set wsSumary = .Sheets("Value_Summary_Sheet")
        Set wsInputs = .Sheets("Inputs")
        Set wsFinMod = .Sheets("Financial Models")
    End With

    With wbPaste
        Set wsPaste = .Sheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    End With

    With wsPaste
        wsSumary.UsedRange.Copy
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues '?¿?¿ I assume from your code you want to paste it there
        .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        .Name = .Cells(1, 3)
    End With

    Dim i As Long, x As Long, wsTemp As Worksheet
    x = wsInputs.Range("Total_Toggles").Value
    For i = 1 To x
        Application.Calculate
        With wbPaste
            Set wsTemp = .Sheets.Add(after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
        End With
        With wsTemp
            wsFinMod.UsedRange.Copy
            .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            .Name = .Cells(1, 3)
        End With
    Next i

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .CutCopyMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the notes throughout they were extremely helpful in walking through the changes. When I tested your method in the model it is no longer cycling through the toggle to roll from 1 to x. This was working before by referencing "Selected_Toggle_Number" a cell name which is a driver on the inputs tab as well. It seems this would be an easy addition to that section of the code but I cannot seem to get it working again now (per your suggested code).

Comment: I figured it out - thank you again for all your help.

Comment: Sorry @AKS I wasn't available, if you need to add to that range you can add + 1 at the end of every iteration like on the `i = i + 1` I thought you were using it as reference but if it does something else it's easy to do. If that answer helped, don't forget to mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to rewrite the first part of your code. It is not a total answer, but can help you understand and rewrite your code. You don't need all the `Activate` or `Select`, you can do a Google search on how to avoid them

```
Dim Destwb As Workbook, Srcewb As Workbook
Set Destwb = Workbooks("Copy_PasteWorkbook")
Set Srcewb = Workbooks("XYZ_v1") 'or "ThisWorkbook" if the source wb is the wb with your macro

    Destwb.Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = "Model" 'add a new worksheet and rename it

    'copy the range from the source workbook
    Srcewb.Sheets("Value_Summary_Sheet").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell)).Copy
    'paste the copied range to the new worksheet in the destination workbook
    Destwb.Sheets("Model").Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues 'all other paramaters are optional

    'change the name of the new worksheet again(you could have set the name to the cell value the first time
    Destwb.Sheets("Model").Name = Cells(1, 3).Value

    'Goto a specific cell in the scource workbook
    Application.Goto Srcewb.Range("A1"), Scroll = True
```